# Android Studio Kotlin background activiy after app closed

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I do that background activity continue to work after the app closed?

I tried to `startService` and start Listener activity

MainActivity:

```
var ser = Intent(this@MainActivity, Listener::class.java)
startService(ser)
```

Listener.tk:

```
package com.example.chatapp

import android.app.IntentService
import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
class Listener : IntentService("Listener") {
    val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    var myRef = database.getReference("Messages")
    override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d("scrpapa", "1")
        var reff = database.getReference("Messages")
        reff.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {
            override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
                val chattmes = p0.getValue(ChatC::class.java)
                if (chattmes != null) {
                    Log.d("asd", "1")
                }

            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            }

            override fun onChildChanged(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
            }

            override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
            }

            override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Service should be foreground or it will be killed
2. Also u can use workers

Comment: Can I do the foreground service without the notification?
https://imgur.com/a/JlQ20IU

Comment: Man I tried this: https://androidwave.com/foreground-service-android-example/
And when I close my app on my phone it's doesn't work